# Wordpress redirect user if not logged in

Tags: php, wordpress, e-commerce

I'm using the following code in functions.php to redirect users who are not logged in, excluding if you are in wp-login.php.

```
if(!is_user_logged_in() && $pagenow != 'wp-login.php') {
wp_redirect( 'http://signup.mysite.com', 302 );
}
```

However, I've installed a shopping cart plugin that uses a different login page and basically redirects mysite.com/wp-login.php to mysite.com/account/login.

Is there some code I can use to exclude url paths from redirecting, perhaps something to replace `$pagenow != 'wp-login.php'`?

Comment: does your shopping cart plugin redirect every path to mysite.com/account/login if not logged in?

Comment: No, you can still browse the site. But if you try to access the standard wp-login.php it will redirect to amysite.com/account/login which is a custom login page.

Answer (score 12):

How about this..

```
//
//  Re-direct not-logged-in users to holding page
//
if(!is_user_logged_in() && curPageURL() != 'http://mysite.com/wp-login.php') {
    wp_redirect( 'http://signup.mysite.com', 302 );
    exit;
}

//
//  Get current page URL
//
function curPageURL() {

    $pageURL = 'http';
    if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}

    $pageURL .= "://";
    if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
        $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    } else {
        $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    }

    return $pageURL;
}
```

Comment: Care to comment your code? Add some explanations on what you have done and why, it adds value to your answer, other than "How about this" and plain code.

Comment: it's pretty obvious what he is doing. curPageURL checks the page you are on. If it matches wp-login, it allows it to load just fine without redirect

Comment: Its not obvious for people still learning - since stackoverflow should enhance selflearning comments are always good to explain and teach why and how the solution provided works.

Answer (score 12):

Open Functions.php...

Paste:

```
// Redirect users who arent logged in...
function login_redirect() {

    // Current Page
    global $pagenow;

    // Check to see if user in not logged in and not on the login page
    if(!is_user_logged_in() && $pagenow != 'wp-login.php')
          // If user is, Redirect to Login form.
          auth_redirect();
}
// add the block of code above to the WordPress template
add_action( 'wp', 'login_redirect' );
```

hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You could experiment with the WordPress `is_page( 'login' )` or maybe `is_page( 'account/login' )` conditionals.

Comment: That didn't seem to work with my setup. Is there a way to redirect users only if they are trying to access the homepage? I tried using is_front_page() but that didn't work.

Comment: if(!is_user_logged_in() && is_front_page()) {
wp_redirect( 'http://signup.mysite.com' );
}

Comment: It looks like you have a stray semicolon right after your redirect url. Try removing that. Also, you might want to consider hooking this into the `pre_get_posts` filter to save some database queries.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php     
if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
?> 
<style>
.lor1{ display:none;}
.lor1.kun{ display: block;}
.lor1.user_not_login{ display: block;}
</style>
<?php }  ?>
```

1. main div(.lor1) means comman div start after **header** and finesh before **footer**
2. Add new class (.lor1.kun) in main div when user loging this main class display: block;
3. make new html Ex. display mess loging frist one (.lor1.user_not_login)

**ADD this code in header.php**