# WordPress - Redirect if not logged in

Tags: wordpress, redirect, private

I am running WordPress, BuddyPress and bbPress. I have viewed the links stated below, but I have been unable to achieve the desired result.

What I wish to achieve is a code for functions.php that will redirect any visitor back to the page 'welcome' if they're not logged in on any area of the site. The code needs to exclude the pages 'welcome', 'register' and 'contact-public'.

Anyone willing to help with this? Any thoughts?

Thanks for your time,

Kieran.

---

URL's

[Wordpress redirect user if not logged in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11238375/wordpress-redirect-user-if-not-logged-in)

[Make Wordpress-blog totally private to logged out visitors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7010694/make-wordpress-blog-totally-private-to-logged-out-visitors)

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the solution mentioned in above URLs that you have posted with [`is_page()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page) check and redirect the user by excluding pages that you mentioned